# prometheus start but not opened on browser

Tags: prometheus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJTmX.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpieX.jpg)
i'm using prometheus docker image (quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.0.0) in kubernetes.
prometheus pod starting and have this logs:

```
kubectl -n monitoring logs -f prometheus-54968887c9-mf4pp
level=info ts=2017-12-11T10:08:33.252046504Z caller=main.go:215 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.0.0, branch=HEAD, revision=0a74f98628a0463dddc90528220c94de5032d1a0)"
level=info ts=2017-12-11T10:08:33.252181297Z caller=main.go:216 build_context="(go=go1.9.2, user=root@615b82cb36b6, date=20171108-07:11:59)"
level=info ts=2017-12-11T10:08:33.252206582Z caller=main.go:217 host_details="(Linux 4.13.9-coreos #1 SMP Thu Oct 26 03:21:00 UTC 2017 x86_64 prometheus-54968887c9-mf4pp (none))"
level=info ts=2017-12-11T10:08:33.25620513Z caller=web.go:380 component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
level=info ts=2017-12-11T10:08:33.258030669Z caller=main.go:314 msg="Starting TSDB"
level=info ts=2017-12-11T10:08:33.25836032Z caller=targetmanager.go:71 component="target manager" msg="Starting target manager..."
```

but i can't open it on browser - i get message "Service Unavailable"

how can i get detailed logs for resolving problem with prometheus?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJTmX.jpg

Comment: the problem is solved.
and solved long ago.
and I forgot how I decided it ))

Comment: it may be happen when the memory is full

Answer (score 1):

Start prometheus with debugging turned on by using the flag `--log.level`:

```
$ /bin/prometheus -h
...
--log.level=info      [debug,
                      info,
                      warn,
                      error]
```

Then, check the container's logs using:

```
docker logs <name of prometheus container>
kubectl logs <name of prometheus pod>
```

Also, is the prometheus port `9090` exposed in the container/pod/service?

([Docs](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/wiki/Default-port-allocations))

Comment: thanks for the answer, i run prometheus with `info` flag and the problem was just a `yml` **typo**.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a non swarmed (no dfproxy or HRM http routing mesh)

Could you confirm if browsing to http://[ip of node running prometheus]:9090, does this return "Service Unavailable" or something different?

Answer (score 0):

Seems web interface not started yet. Wait Until this line appear in log:

> level=info ts=2021-12-08T14:35:36.208059615Z caller=main.go:587
> msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."

I had that problem with slow start at RaspberyPI. And start google why I see "Service Unavailable" . After googling I try refresh web interface another one an it's became unfrozed.